# In VScode, When I use Shortcut key Ctrl + / to make comment in HTML file, it doesn't work right like this "{{! }}"

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

When I use the shortcut key to make comment in an HTML file, it doesn't work.

Originally, I expect `<!-- -->` when i type <kbd>Ctrl + /</kbd> but now result is `{{! }}`.

I don't know what does sign that.

Please teach me how to fix that if you have had fixed the same problem...

Comment: Looks like some extension might be overriding the default behavior. Go to File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> search for `Ctrl+/`. Are you seeing multiple key bindings for `Ctrl+/` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to make sure that your HTML file has proper `.html` extension. And check the language mode associated with that file in your VScode status bar.
[See this status bar showing HTML language model for my .html file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKMsC.png)